# Unable to run OAF page in JDeveloper in Oracle EBS R12

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, ojdbc, oc4j

I've been following this Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xTfRIRPsNU to run a OAF page in JDeveloper in Oracle E-Business Suite R12

As shown in the video I made a successful database connection from JDeveloper to Oracle EBS through the correct DBC file, I opened the sample projects I got with JDeveloper and set all necessary Runtime Connection information. After rebuilding the included 'tutorial' project, I reached the final step, ie, running 'HomePG.xml', but I'm unable to run the page and I'm getting the following in the message log:

```
16/07/18 12:37:47 WARNING: Code-source /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/xml.jar (from <library> in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevhome/jdev/system/oracle.j2ee.10.1.3.43.6/embedded-oc4j/config/application.xml) has the same filename but is not identical to /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/lib/xml.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader default.root:0.0.0.
16/07/18 12:37:47 WARNING: Code-source /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/jazn.jar (from <library> in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevhome/jdev/system/oracle.j2ee.10.1.3.43.6/embedded-oc4j/config/application.xml) has the same filename but is not identical to /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/jazn.jar (from <code-source> in META-INF/boot.xml in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader default.root:0.0.0.
16/07/18 12:37:47 WARNING: Code-source /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/jazncore.jar (from manifest of /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/jazn.jar) has the same filename but is not identical to /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/jazncore.jar (from <code-source> in META-INF/boot.xml in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader default.root:0.0.0.
Ready message received from Oc4jNotifier.
Embedded OC4J startup time: 3907 ms.

Target URL -- http://127.0.1.1:8989/OA_HTML/runregion.jsp
16/07/18 12:37:48 Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0)  initialized
```

and the page opens as follows:
[image]

Note: For above execution, under Embedded OC4J Server Preferences->Java Compiler-> Compiler: ojc, Bin Directory: /home/user/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/bin/

Changing the Bin Directory to the JDK's bin, didn't do any good and produced a similar error page with the difference : 'ojc not found under /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22, specify the correct location of ojc in server.xml using the  tag '

Then I tried changing the following in Java Compiler-> Compiler: javac, Bin Directory: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/bin

And produced a different message log:

```
16/07/18 11:49:55 WARNING: Code-source /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/xml.jar (from <library> in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevhome/jdev/system/oracle.j2ee.10.1.3.43.6/embedded-oc4j/config/application.xml) has the same filename but is not identical to /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/lib/xml.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader default.root:0.0.0.
16/07/18 11:49:55 WARNING: Code-source /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/jazn.jar (from <library> in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevhome/jdev/system/oracle.j2ee.10.1.3.43.6/embedded-oc4j/config/application.xml) has the same filename but is not identical to /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/jazn.jar (from <code-source> in META-INF/boot.xml in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader default.root:0.0.0.
16/07/18 11:49:55 WARNING: Code-source /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/jazncore.jar (from manifest of /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/jazn.jar) has the same filename but is not identical to /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/jazncore.jar (from <code-source> in META-INF/boot.xml in /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader default.root:0.0.0.
Ready message received from Oc4jNotifier.
Embedded OC4J startup time: 3571 ms.
16/07/18 11:49:56 Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0)  initialized

Target URL -- http://127.0.1.1:8989/OA_HTML/runregion.jsp
16/07/18 11:49:57 TIME: runregion: initialization [1 ms] 
18 Jul, 2016 11:49:58 AM oracle.jsp.logger.JspMessages infoCannotDispatchJspPage
INFO: Unable to dispatch JSP Page : oracle.jsp.provider.JspCompileException: <H3>Errors compiling:/home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevhome/jdev/myclasses/.jsps//_OAErrorPage.java</H3><TABLE BORDER=1 WIDTH=100%><TR><TH ALIGN=CENTER>Line #</TH><TH ALIGN=CENTER>Error</TH></TR><TR><TD WIDTH=7% VALIGN=TOP><P ALIGN=CENTER>9</TD><TD>[jsp src:line #:16]<br> cannot access oracle.apps.fnd.common.WebRequestUtil
bad class file: /home/qbuser/jdev10g_install/jdevbin/jdev/appslibrt/atg.zip(oracle/apps/fnd/common/WebRequestUtil.class)
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
import oracle.apps.fnd.common.WebRequestUtil;
                              </TD></TR></TABLE>
```

And page error:

[image]

My Oracle EBS version is 12.2.4 which I'm running through VirtualBox 5.1 for Linux hosts. My JDeveloper version is 10.1.3.5, which is the compatible version for the above mentioned Oracle Apps version.

I want to know what the reason might be that I can't run the page. I've been at this for days now. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this?

Comment: No, I have not been successful in finding a solution. I tried two other versions of EBS, 12.2.3 and also 12.2.1 but reached the same issue when following the tutorial mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

have you assigned the relevant responsibilities to your user in EBS and have you configured the correct responsibility short code in jDeveloper run time properties. If yes it should work additionally check with your DBA to verify the DBC file you are using, sometimes the DBC file has an issue.